# How to design conditional content control using OpenDoPE add-in

Tags: xpath, ms-word, docx4j

Iam using OpenDoPE add-in(First/Old version), I have a table design like follows

[image]

I have an xml data like follows

```html
<myxml>
 <rows>
 <row>
  <name>Abhilash Shajan</name>
  <company>Standout</company>
  <designation>Developer</designation>
                <age>20</age>
 </row>
 <row>
  <name>Sam Thomas</name>
  <company>Allianze</company>
  <designation>Tester</designation>
                <age>27</age>
 </row>
 <row>
  <name>Pradhap</name>
  <company>UST</company>
  <designation>SQL developer</designation>
                <age>26</age>
 </row>
 <row>
  <name>Ragesh</name>
  <company>IBS</company>
  <designation>Tester</designation>
                <age>22</age>
 </row>
   </rows>
</myxml>
```

I need to apply condition to my repeating content control(here the row node is the repeating content control). Here is my condition, If age is greater than 25 then that row should not be visible.

How to write this condition in my OpenDoPE task pane.

Iam a beginner to this add-in can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional content control should be wrapped around (ie contain) the row, and the repeat content control should be wrapped around the conditional content control.

You might find it easier to first add the conditional content control, then add the repeat content control.

Comment: Can you please tell me the expression should be written for this condition in my OpenDoPE taskpane?

Comment: it will show if the XPath evaluates to true, so try something like not( number(/myxml/rows/row[1]/age) > 25).